# Android Interfaces and onCreate()

Tags: android, interface, onclicklistener

This is a double question about using interfaces - namely onclickListener (and related) within an Activity.

1. onCreate should be short - so says the documentation - but if I have lots and lots of views all of which have onClickListeners it can get quite long. I'm worried this will cause the UI thread to timeout. Is this a problem?
2. Is there a best way to use onClickListener? By which I mean, is it better for the Activity to implement onCLickListener and then have a very long onClick() method? Or do the following:

   ```
   mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      ...
    });
   ```

for each View? Does it really make any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. They mean "short" in that don't do anything that takes a long time to process in `onCreate()`.  Anything like math computations, networks or database access, extremely large bitmaps inflations should be done in a thread.  The only overhead that setting an `onClickListener` to a view is calling a method, setting a reference, and usually creating an object.  If object creation does any of the aforementioned things, then it would be best to pre-load the object before creating it.
2. There's no real difference.  What you choose depends entirely on your implentation and coding stye.  Using an anonymous object like you showed is kind of like a "set-and-forget" style way of doing it.  It's suitable if the action is unique to the button.  Creating a whole new class that that implements `onClickListener()` would be required if there needs to be a state that persists with each click.  That way, you create the object once and set all the necessary views to the single object.  It may also be useful to do it in that fashion if many views do the same action when clicked.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't bother with the loading of your activity because the code inside `onClick` listener is executed only when a click is made on its view.

Besides, its not a good idea to execute heavy stuff (network, database, drawable manipulation, etc.) in **onCreate**. In case if you really need to do such processing then off-load it to an `AsyncTask` which runs your code in a separate thread causing your UI (main) thread to be free.

Answer (score 2):

1) I agree with Deev's answer.

2) Please note that if you choose to use the anonymous inner class solution

```
mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
...
});
```

You create an object for each assignment.
Conversely if you implement `OnClickListener` in your activity you won't create any other object. This doesn't make so much difference for a small number of object but could save some memory (and save you from GC) for larger number (and you said to have a lots and lots) of objects. Avoid unuseless object creation is suggested in [Designing for Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/performance.html#object_creation)

Comment: There is some overhead in creating objects, but I think overall the effect would make miniscule difference.  Majority of the time, OnClickListener() are created once on View creation and they remain for the existence of the View itself.  This means that the GC will run and remove the OnClickListener() only when the View is being destroyed anyway which has way more overhead.

It is something to keep in mind if there's something slowing you down during optimization phase.

Comment: We agree that this is not a big deal in normal cases. I mentioned for completeness and also because he said to have a lot of views.